# When should I use Audio vs Sound Data types?

Tags: sound, data-types, head

It seems like mathematica has 2 related data types [Audio](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) and [sound](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sound.html).

Why is there 2 separate data types? When would I use one versus the other?

---

### Guesses

I know I can convert between them by `Audio[Sound[…]]`. But without knowing why, it seems like unnecessary complication.

I thought it might be because sound doesn't support sampling, but you can create sampled sound objects with  `SampledSoundFunction[f,n,r]` .

The other thing I might guess is Audio can do stereo?

It also seems like some functions are only available in one datatype or the other, so then I have to go back and forth between the 2 if I want to use both. Is there a better way to do things?

---

### Context

For example, I might like to multiply a violin sound by a sin wave. I can make both of them as sound objects using `SoundNote`. Then, I have to convert them to Audio objects. After which I can multiply them together.
e.g.

```
a = SoundNote[...]
b = SoundNote[...]
c = Audio[a]*Audio[b]
```

Not only is this clunky, but how do I convert c back to a `Sound` object. Also, the Audio command always shifts the sound waveform to be centered around 0. This means I can't multiply a violin sound by say (1 + SquareWave[t]).

Can I convert an Audio file to a function?

Comment: `Audio` is new, and is specialized for waveforms. Use `Audio` if you only deal with waveforms. `Sound` is old, and also supports a symbolic representation of music (MIDI). Maybe this will help: `Audio` is to `Sound` as `Image` is to `Graphics`.